# Create function to filter out data that meets a specific condition in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a report in SQL Server 2012. The report is pulling out discharge patients information from database. The report only needs to show patients the third admission day information.

For example, patient A was admitted into the hospital on January 01/2016, (stayed for 4 days) January 02, January 03, January 04 and was discharged on January 05/2016.

Patient B was admitted into the hospital on January 15/2016, (stayed for 6 days) January 16, January 17, January 18, January 19, January 20 and was discharged on January 21/2016.

The report only needs to show the third day's (January 03 and January 17) information.

How to write the function to filter out the data only show necessary data? Any suggestions?

Greatly appreciate your big help!

Thanks!

Rose

Comment: see my edit for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `Row_Number()` and `Partition by`. Basically you partition by the patient and you row_number based on the date ascending.

```
Select ... ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY patientId Order by TheDate)
```

Then you can use that above as a sub query and filter `where t.theRow = 3`.

Sorry I'm on an iPod so it's difficult to provide more info. I'll try to clean this up or format it tomorrow.

### Edit

Now that I'm on a PC, here's what you can do per above

```
SELECT
 t.PatientID,
 t.TheNumber
FROM
 (
   Select
     PatientID,
     ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY YourDateField) AS   TheNumber
   FROM
     YourTable
 ) t
WHERE
 t.TheNumber = 3
```

Comment: @Rose - Great let me know if you have any issues - here to help!

Comment: Sure JonH, will keep you updated. Thanks for your great help:)

Comment: Everything is fine now. Thanks:)

Comment: Can you accept the answer to close this issue out please?

Comment: Hi JonH, I just came back from vacation. Actually I posted my comments a while ago but didn't see it so I write it again. Thanks for your big help! Your above codes works very well but I need to join other tables to get all the information: Patient_table to get patientname; Discharge_table to get dischargedate so on. How to write the sql? Sorry, I am really not good at writing complex codes.

Comment: Simple now just use the derived table, t, and join to all other tables since you have the patient ID.  I'm on a mobile device but I can help more Monday?

Comment: Thanks JonH! You are the best :)